# Openopt - DerApproximator package not found

Tags: python, environment-variables, nonlinear-optimization

While trying to solve a Non Linear Problem in Python using `Openopt`'s `NLP.solve()` I get this error, summarized as

> you should have DerApproximator installed.

I tried

```
pip install derapproximator
```

but it says "requirement already satisfied".

I am using Windows 7 x64, Python 3.4 with OpenOpt 0.5604. How do I install this package?

### Here is the complete text from the command window.

```
solution = problem.solve('ralg')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\baseProblem.py", line 253, in solve
return runProbSolver(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\runProbSolver.py", line 292, in runProbSolver solver(p)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\solvers\UkrOpt\ralg_oo.py", line 159, in __solver__
g = bestPoint._getDirection(self.approach)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\Point.py", line 640, in _getDirection
self.direction = self.sum_of_all_active_constraints_gradient()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\Point.py", line 565, in sum_of_all_active_constraints_gradient
tmp = p.dc(x, ind)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\baseProblem.py", line 550, in <lambda>
self.wrapped_1st_derivatives(x, ind, funcType, ignorePrev, useSparse))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\nonLinFuncs.py", line 383, in wrapped_1st_derivatives
derivatives = p.wrapped_func(x, ind, funcType, True, True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\nonLinFuncs.py", line 28, in wrapped_func
p.err('For the problem you should have DerApproximator installed, see http://openopt.org/DerApproximator')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openopt-0.5604-py3.4.egg\openopt\kernel\oologfcn.py", line 16, in ooerr
raise OpenOptException(msg)
oologfcn.OpenOptException: For the problem you should have DerApproximator installed, see http://openopt.org/DerApproximator
```

### Update 1

I saw a file named `derapproximator-0.52-py3.4.egg` in the `Python34\Lib\site-packages` the path which I had to add as `PYTHONPATH` key in the `Environment variables` for openopt to be found by python. I did not know how a file with `.egg` extension could be used there so I extracted the contents to `derapproximator-0.52-py3.4`. Whose folder hierarchy on cmd tree looks like

```
+---derapproximator-0.52-py3.4
|   +---DerApproximator
|   |   \---__pycache__
|   \---EGG-INFO
```

but the error is still the same,

```
>>> import derapproximator
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'derapproximator'
```

Then again I tried with renaming the folder to `derapproximator-0.52-py3.4.egg` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You may want to remove the `nlp` tag: That's for natural language processing, not non-linear problems.

Comment: Thank you @JohnWiseman. I have corrected the tag.